# How do I access a remote aws lightsail mongodb over ssh tunnel

Tags: mongodb, ssh-tunnel, amazon-lightsail

I have a Lightsail AWS instance up and running with a MEAN stack. I have an existing MEAN stack running on a different network. At the moment the node server.js connects to localhost for the mongo bit (on same machine) and all I want to do is replace the localhost with a connection to my mongo running on my AWS remote server.

I understand, that for security reasons, it is best to ssh tunnel this connection, which I think I am familiar with.

What I have done so far is this:

In a console on the machine hosting the node server (remote to the db) I have run:

```
ssh -L 8181:127.0.0.1:80 -i ~/LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-eu-west-2.pem bitnami@31.16.56.125 -N
```

I can then browse to the RockMongo UI from the local machine using localhost:8181/rockmongo ...yay.

If I then run the following:

```
ssh -L 8181:127.0.0.1:27017 -i ~/LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-eu-west-2.pem bitnami@31.16.56.125 -N
```

(27017 being the mongo port)

Then try and access the db from my remote machine using:

```
mongo --username XXXXXX --password XXXXXX 31.16.56.125:8181/testdata
```

I get the following error:

> ~]
>   2017-12-28T22:11:09.791+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 31.16.56.125:8181 (31.16.56.125), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
>   exception: connect failed

Am I doing this wrong? i.e. is the tunnel only for http connections and not mongo command line use? Do I need to test the connection some other way?

I've Googled all over the place for this and not had much luck (a lot of the AWS docs suggest punching a hole in the firewall - which one can no longer do!)

Answer (score 0):

OK I've (partially) solved this, there were a few things wrong.

1) The mongo client was 2.6 and mongo running on AWS was 3.4. Upgrading this solved some issues - in that I was getting a more meaningful error message.

One thing I did have trouble with is that apt-get seemed to perform an update, yet the version reported when issuing the mongo command was still 2.6.

To solve this I had to run `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*` (note the asterisk). Then perform the update.... If you need to do this then follow these instructions: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

2) This command

```
mongo --username XXXXXX --password XXXXXX 31.16.56.125:8181/testdata
```

won't work as I've omitted 'admin' from it and not specified localhost!

but

```
mongo admin --username XXXXXX --password XXXXXX localhost:8181/testdata
```

doesn't work either and gives the following output.

```
2018-01-03T22:00:42.380+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2018-01-03T22:00:42.380+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6
```

The only command I could get to work is:

```
mongo admin --username XXXXXX --password XXXXXX --port 8181
```

The default host is localhost, so in this case it uses the tunnel, this will also just connect to the test db, you can then admin from there.

What I haven't got to the bottom of is the specification of the host:port/db  as an argument as per the output from running `mongo --help`

```
usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
db address can be:
  foo                   foo database on local machine
  192.169.0.5/foo       foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine
  192.169.0.5:9999/foo  foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine on port 9999
```